# couchbase: using java query view ERROR Connection timed out

Tags: java, couchbase

I use your sample code in couchbases' site,I'm using java and the jdk version is 1.6.Setting and getting values by key are Ok,but when querying the view ,there is always an error.

Here is my code:

```
package src.main.java;
import com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.Query;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.View;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.ViewResponse;
import com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.ViewRow;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


    public class HelloWorld {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // (Subset) of nodes in the cluster to establish a connection
        List<URI> hosts = Arrays.asList(
          new URI("http://192.168.174.128:8091/pools")
        );
        // Name of the Bucket to connect to
        String bucket = "default";
        // Password of the bucket (empty) string if none
        String password = "";
        // Connect to the Cluster
        CouchbaseClient client = new CouchbaseClient(hosts, bucket, password);

        // 1: Load the View infos
        String designDoc = "users";
        String viewName = "by_firstname";
        View view = client.getView(designDoc, viewName);
        // 2: Create a Query object to customize the Query
        Query query = new Query();
        query.setIncludeDocs(true); // Include the full document body

        // 3: Actually Query the View and return the results
        ViewResponse response = client.query(view, query);

        // 4: Iterate over the Data and print out the full document
        for (ViewRow row : response) {
          System.out.println(row.getDocument());
        }
        // Shutting down properly
        client.shutdown();
      }
    }
```

Here is the error log

```
2013-08-03 11:17:21.779 ERROR com.couchbase.client.ViewNode$EventLogger:  Connection timed out: [192.168.174.128/192.168.174.128:8092]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out waiting for operation
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:67)
    at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.getView(CouchbaseClient.java:483)
    at src.main.java.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:75)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for operation
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.waitForAndCheckOperation(HttpFuture.java:85)
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:74)
    at com.couchbase.client.internal.HttpFuture.get(HttpFuture.java:64)
    ... 2 more
```

From the Web Administration Console I can see I have already published the view.It's also works In that console.Firewall has been closed,and I have tried couchbase 2.0.0 Community edition and 2.1.1 Community edition.

Comment: Did you end up resolving this? If so, what did you do?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue recently. The view works fine in the admin console, but the client times out on the call to getView(). This can happen anytime the HTTP request to get the view definition times out or fails, which can / will happen on any network.

getView() simply fetches the definition of the view for you to query against. According to the official Couchbase documentation you should actually cache those View definitions in your application instead of calling getView() every time you need to run a query.

> Every time you call the .getView(String, String) method on the CouchbaseClient object, an HTTP request is sent to the server. As you’ve seen in the previous sections, a View object is nothing more than a representation of what the view is about. This information won’t change much in production.
>
> As a best practice, call getView only once, and then cache the returned object and reuse it for every subsequent query call. That way you not only save bandwidth and latency, it also reduces the amount of work the server needs to do.

SOURCE: http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-java-1.4/#reusing-view-definitions